# Refresh displayed data on click in Django app

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, duplicates, refresh

I am using Ajax to get the appropriate url that displays orders based on the date that was clicked in a calendar. This works, but every time user clicks on a date, the content duplicates, not removing the previous display.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEdWg.png

I would like the content to refresh, when the user clicks on a date again. How would I do that?

I was searching for a "Jquery refresh DIV", and stumbled upon location.reload(), ajax.reload(), jquery load method, and similar solutions. I tried implementing these, but not sure if they are the right solution for my case.

Here is my code. Please let me know if I should post anything else. Help appreciated.

`.js`

```
$(function () {
var $archive = $('#orders-per-day');
$(".day-click").click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var day = $(this)[0].innerText;
var month = $(".month")[0].innerText.substring(0, 3);
var year = $(".month")[0].innerText.substr(-4);
console.log(year);
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: `/ocal/date/${year}/${month}/${day}/`,
  success: function (data) {
    $archive.append(data);
    }
  })
 });
});
```

`html template` for showing the orders of one day

```
{% extends 'ocal/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Orders for {{ day }}</h1>
<ul>
  {% if object_list %}
  {% for order in object_list %}
  <li>
    <a href="/ocal/{{ order.id }}/detail">Order {{ order.id }} </a>
    {{ order.status_str }}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
  <p>No orders</p>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Code from `python` file where the class Calendar is created, and where day is formatted as table data.

```
return f"<td><a href='' id='day_{day}' class='day-click' value='{day}'><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul>{d}</ul></a></td>"
```

Comment: `$archive.append(data)` appends as the function says. You should use a div for which you want to **replace** the content. `$archive.html(data)` would do that, except I'm not sure `$archive` is the correct div in this case. But you get the idea.

Comment: `$archive` is the div where I am loading the data. It exists in `Calendar.html` template. `$archive.html(data)` does the same thing as `$archive.append(data)` in this case. When you say to use a div for which I want to replace the content, my understanding is to use a div of the content that is being loaded into the `$archive` div. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, it should be a div that is **outside** the content being loaded (otherwise you're loading new content into the previously loaded content, hence nested/duplicated content). It should just be a placeholder (empty) div in your receiving template. With `html(<htmlString>)` you just **set** its content to `data` so if there was content in it previously it gets replaced.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your initial suggestion works. I thought it didn't because I added the `$archive.html(data)` to a wrong js file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$archive.append(data)` **appends** as the function says.

You should use a placeholder `<div>` for which you want to **replace** the content. `$archive.html(data)` would do that, except I'm not sure `$archive` is the correct `div` in this case. But you get the idea.